# Images not getting rendered in wicked_pdf's pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Here I am not talking about the images with `wicked_pdf_image_tag`. Those are working well.
But I have a body with images in it.

```
<%= @product_info.body %>
```

This body contains images and they are rendering like a small box.

[image]

The small height rectangle is actually an image. I don't know why it's not rendering properly.

My gemfile has

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Pls help.

Comment: `body` I presume is a string. It probably a html representation of your document. How are the images in there entered. <img> tag? What are the attributes? Does the image come from url? relative or absolute? base64? Am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes body is text. I am using <img > tags.

Comment: and what is the src attribute of the img tag?

Comment: I am mostly using urls

Comment: Why do I need to ask the same question 3 times. I asked in first comment already about the urls. Now 3 comments later I'm still asking the same thing. Are they relative or absolute or base64 or something else?

Comment: Ok I am using <img src="urls"> and they are absolute. No base64.